# Java - create group of dates by Month from 2 dates

Tags: java, date, java-time, localdate

Using Java 8

**Goal**

From two dates (for example: firstDay 2018-09-01 and lastDay 2018-11-10), I would like to create two arrays of firstDay and lastDay created by month. For example:

```
List<LocalDate> firstDays = [2018-09-01,2018-10-01,2018-11-01]
List<LocalDate> lastDays = [2018-09-30, 2018-10-31,2018-11-10]
```

Eventually, I would like this method to apply also for years (for example: firstDay 2018-12-10 and lastDay 2019-01-06).

**Issue**

I don't now what to use to fullfill that goal. I'm still searching. Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is basically just a problem statement.

Comment: for the lastDays did you mean `2018-11-10` or `2018-11-30` ?

Comment: for the lastDays I mean 2018-11-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an iterative style, and handling edge cases:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 9, 1);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 10);

List<LocalDate> firstDays = new ArrayList<>();
List<LocalDate> lastDays = new ArrayList<>();

LocalDate firstOfMonth = startDate.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate lastOfMonth = startDate.withDayOfMonth(startDate.lengthOfMonth());

while (firstOfMonth.isBefore(endDate)) {
    firstDays.add(firstOfMonth.isBefore(startDate) ? startDate : firstOfMonth);
    lastDays.add(endDate.isBefore(lastOfMonth) ? endDate : lastOfMonth);

    firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
    lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.withDayOfMonth(firstOfMonth.lengthOfMonth());
}

System.out.println(firstDays);
System.out.println(lastDays);
```

Output:

```
[2018-09-01, 2018-10-01, 2018-11-01]
[2018-09-30, 2018-10-31, 2018-11-10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `plusMonth` like so :

```
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.parse("2018-09-01");
LocalDate lastDay = LocalDate.parse("2018-11-10");

Long timeBetween = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(firstDay, lastDay);

// First day of firstDays is not changeable so add it like it is
List<LocalDate> firstDays = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(firstDay));

// Generate the dates between the start and end date
firstDays.addAll(LongStream.rangeClosed(1, timeBetween)
        .mapToObj(f -> firstDay.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(f))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

// For the lastDays, generate the dates
List<LocalDate> lastDays = LongStream.range(0, timeBetween)
        .mapToObj(f -> {
            LocalDate newDate = firstDay.plusMonths(f);
            return newDate.withDayOfMonth(newDate.lengthOfMonth());
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Last day of lastDays is not changeable so add it like it is
lastDays.add(lastDay);
```

**Output**

```
[2018-09-01, 2018-10-01, 2018-11-01]
[2018-09-30, 2018-10-31, 2018-11-10]
```

Comment: Nice use of streams, but I think `lastDays` is wrong for the last element: it should be `2018-11-10` and not `2018-11-30`

Comment: Thank you @AlexM oops I don't see this, I will fix it, but I think it is a typo?

Comment: I think the user expects to see `firstDay` instead of the 1st of the first month, and `lastDay` instead of the last day of the last month. It was not made clear in the question but kinda makes sense.

Comment: Yes Alex M and YCF_L. I'm trying both versions. Yours and the iterative one below. I tested first the iterative one, because the first firstDay and the last lastDay correspond to the real two dates entered. Thanks a lot for your help. I need to do some code on top for my purpose. I tell you if it works.

Comment: @ManuelaCodingPadawan check my update I was wrong, thank you AlexM too

Comment: YCF_L thanks it works. I use the one of AlexM because I understand it better. But both are working. Thanks to you and to @AlexM.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good answers already. Allow me to see if I can still devise something elegant.

### Create just one list of objects

First, I suggest that you don’t want two lists. That’s an anti-pattern described here: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). Since each first day belongs to a corresponding last day from the other list, everything will be more convenient and less error-prone when you keep them together. For this purpose you may use some library class or devise your own:

```
public class DateInterval {

    LocalDate firstDay;
    LocalDate lastDay;

    public DateInterval(LocalDate firstDay, LocalDate lastDay) {
        if (lastDay.isBefore(firstDay)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dates in wrong order");
        }
        this.firstDay = firstDay;
        this.lastDay = lastDay;
    }

    // getters and other stuff

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + firstDay + " - " + lastDay;
    }

}
```

With this class we need just one list:

```
    LocalDate firstDayOverall = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.DECEMBER, 10);
    LocalDate lastDayOverall = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 6);

    if (lastDayOverall.isBefore(firstDayOverall)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Overall dates in wrong order");
    }
    LocalDate firstDayOfLastMonth = lastDayOverall.withDayOfMonth(1);
    LocalDate currentFirstDay = firstDayOverall;
    List<DateInterval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    while (currentFirstDay.isBefore(firstDayOfLastMonth)) {
        intervals.add(new DateInterval(currentFirstDay, currentFirstDay.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())));
        currentFirstDay = currentFirstDay.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1);
    }
    intervals.add(new DateInterval(currentFirstDay, lastDayOverall));

    System.out.println("Intervals: " + intervals);
```

The output from the above code snippet is:

> Intervals: [2018-12-10 - 2018-12-31, 2019-01-01 - 2019-01-06]

The special case of first and last day being in the same month is handled by the loop not looping at all and the `add` after the loop adding the single interval to the list.

### If two lists of dates are required

If you do insist on two lists, the two-arg `datesUntil` method is handy:

```
    List<LocalDate> firstDays = new ArrayList<>();
    firstDays.add(firstDayOverall);
    // first day not to be included in first days
    LocalDate endExclusive = lastDayOverall.withDayOfMonth(1).plusMonths(1);
    List<LocalDate> remainingFirstDays = firstDayOverall.withDayOfMonth(1)
            .plusMonths(1)
            .datesUntil(endExclusive, Period.ofMonths(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    firstDays.addAll(remainingFirstDays);
    System.out.println("First days: " + firstDays);

    // Calculate last days as the day before each first day except the first
    List<LocalDate> lastDays = remainingFirstDays.stream()
            .map(day -> day.minusDays(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    lastDays.add(lastDayOverall);
    System.out.println("Last days:  " + lastDays);
```

Output:

> ```
> First days: [2018-12-10, 2019-01-01]
> Last days:  [2018-12-31, 2019-01-06]
> ```

### Aside

At first I had a feeling that the `YearMonth` class would make for an elegant solution. I realized, however, that it would have required special treatment of first and last month, so I don’t think it could have led to more elegant code than what we have above. You may try if you like.